# How to draw identity morphism in tikz-cd?

Tags: tikz-pgf

A figure in *Wikipedia: Category (mathematics)* as follows:
[image]

I can write a version without id morphism:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[rd,swap,"f\circ g"]
  \arrow{r}{f} &
B \arrow{d}{g} \\
& C
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How to add the **id morphism**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `loop`. `loop left` and `loop right` might be good enough for you (`above` and `below` are also options), if not you can set the angles yourself with `out=<angle1>,in=<angle2>,loop`, as shown for `B`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[rd,swap,"f\circ g"]
  \arrow{r}{f}
  \arrow[loop left,"1_A"] &
B \arrow{d}{g}
  \arrow[out=65,in=25,loop,"1_B"] \\
& C
  \arrow[loop right,"1_C"]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```